# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable what does it mean?

Tags: python

```
from random import uniform

def e(x):
    n=len(x)
    return(sum(x)/n)

    def dmean(e,x,new):
    n=len(x)
    return((e*n+new)/(n+1))

    l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,78]
    e(l)

    for i in range(0,5):
    l.append(uniform(0,10))
    e=e(l)
    d=dmean(e,l,uniform(0,10))
```

Answer (score 7):

You have a function named `e`. The first time through the `for` loop, you overwrite the function name by creating a variable of the same name `e=e(l)`. The next time through the loop, it tries to call the function, but `e` is now a `float` value which can't be called. You can fix this by choosing a different name for your variable:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    l.append(uniform(0,10))
    e_value=e(l)
    d=dmean(e_value,l,uniform(0,10))
```

As you can see, Python doesn't distinguish between variable names and function names, so you have to make sure not to use the same name for a variable and a function.